# how to make nodejs server available online from aws win

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services

I have aws windows server 64bit
installed nodejs on it
uploaded nodejs project
run `node server.js`
on aws i can access my node application on url `localhost:8080`
i want to make it available online

in windows firewall every thing is green
I have created new inbound rule for port 8080 and allowed that is also green

Comment: This question is mostly about network infrastructure and thus is probably off-topic here (not really about programming).  It's also been asked many, many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the instance's [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) to permit inbound connections on port 8080. A security group acts as a virtual firewall for the instances associated with it. By default no inbound connections are permitted.